# Why javascript catched exception is empty object

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, exception, error-handling

```
try {
    let tmp = null;
    tmp.split(',');
}
catch (e) {
    Logger().info('catched error: ', e, e.constructor);
}
```

result:

```
catched error:  {} undefined
```

I was trying to use JSON.stringify with the same result.
Why I didn't get any message of error reason?

Comment: What does the implementation of `Logger().info` look like?

Comment: Its just simple wrapper around of winston logger

Comment: This might be related: https://github.com/winstonjs/winston/issues/1338

Comment: Ha! Just replaced with console.log gets the trick! Thanks! Hmmmm...

Comment: @AlexandrLyumitskij well you'll need to have a look at your Winston configuration and how it handles deserializing error objects / functions.

Answer (score 0):

Print the error stack:

```
try {
  let tmp = null;
  tmp.split(',');
}
catch (e) {
  Logger().info('catched error: ', e, e.stack);
  //catched error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null ...
}
```